# Let gh be a chord of a circle ω which is not a diameter, and let A be a fixed point on gh

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, circles

Let segment gh be a chord of a circle ω which is not a diameter, and let n be a fixed point on gh. For which point b on  arc gh is the length n minimized?

Comment: As close as possible to point S doesn't sound correct to me. A straight radial line from the circle center through A will meet the arc at X and would yield the shortest distance XA.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering why a straight radial line would be the shortest distance

Comment: The shortest distance from a point inside a circle to the circumference is a line perpendicular to the circumference, that is, along a radial line.

Comment: @user604720 Dont edit your post like this. You may be blocked for doing things like this

Answer (score 1):

HINT.

Chord and arc are there only to distract you. Given a point $A$ inside a circle, which point of the circle is the nearest to $A$?